# IBM MQ .Net Client v9.1.4 cannot connect to MQ server 8.0.0.4 CompCode: 2 Reason: 2059

Tags: c#, websphere, ibm-mq

This is excerpt of program which throws an exception with code MQException (CompCode: 2 Reason: 2059)

```
                Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();

                properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _host);
                properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _port);
                properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _channel);

               _mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager(_manager, properties);
```

I have setup trace log which produces [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mttwusDVEevCDyASIGtM7I9pWEUaqvek). Small excerpt of it :

```
000002B4 14:45:52.635100   16832.1      0x00000000 0B 08 00 00                                     : ..
000002B5 14:45:52.635100   16832.1    ----}  MQFAP.NmqiConnect(String,NmqiConnectOptions,MQConnectOptions,Hconn,Phconn,out int,out int,ManagedHconn) rc=OK
000002B6 14:45:52.636100   16832.1     System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dest
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Array.CopyTo(Array array, Int32 index)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQFAPMQCNO.set_ConnTag(Byte[] value)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQFAP.NmqiConnect(String name, NmqiConnectOptions pNmqiConnectOpts, MQConnectOptions cno, Hconn remoteParentHconn, Phconn pHconn, Int32& compCode, Int32& reason, ManagedHconn rcnHconn)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQFAP.MQCONNX(String pQMgrName, MQConnectOptions pConnectOpts, Phconn phconn, Int32& pCompCode, Int32& pReason)
000002B7 14:45:52.636100   16832.1    ---}  MQFAP.MQCONNX(String,MQConnectOptions,Phconn,out int,out int) rc=OK
000002B8 14:45:52.636100   16832.1     IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager#01475D71 throwing MQException: cc=2 rc=2059
000002B9 14:45:52.636100   16832.1     New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2059
000002BA 14:45:52.662095   16832.1    --}! MQQueueManager.Connect() rc=(Unknown(2059))
```

Server side Windows Event Log:

```
2/6/2020 16:00:18 - Process(4472.130285) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe) Host(MQ-TEIRESIAS-T) Installation(MQTest) VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(MQ.EXTSERVICES)

Error on receive from host 10.0.8.46.

An error occurred receiving data from 10.0.8.46 over TCP/IP. This may be due to a communications failure.

The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these values and tell the systems administrator.
```

**This is working code with amqmdnet.dll (9.0.0.0)**

We appreciate any help or how can contact IBM Support for this

Comment: I think there was an APAR raised for this issue

Comment: Can you post a link

Comment: Based on your error check if  `_manager`  is null or an empty string.

Comment: it is not and all others parameters are correct, with previous version of amqmdnet.dll (9.0.0.0) all is going alright

Comment: @subbaraoc said he thinks an APAR was already raised on this.   Your options are to contact IBM if you have a support contract or try another version.   9.1.4 is in the continuous delivery stream,  as such it may be less stable.   I would suggest [9.1.0.4 LTS](https://www.google.com/search?q=MQC91) or [9.0.0 8 LTS](https://www.google.com/search?q=MQC9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in APAR [IT31572](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT31572). Fix provided by IBM, tested and verified OK. Released v9.1 CD 9.1.5

Comment: A link with more details for further reference would be nice.

Comment: Will provide more information as soon as I receive a response from IBM. APAR IT31572 is not yet publicly available. Fix was provided directly via IBM support portal.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel A link would not be possible if the APAR has not yet closed.  datapaal, can you find out from IBM which levels of MQ this impacts, (for example was it introduced only in 9.1.4 CDS release?  Does it impact only the .net standard library (amqmdnetstd.dll) which was introduced only in the 9.1.1 CDS releases and added to NuGet only as of 9.1.4?

Comment: @JoshMc Awaiting feedback from IBM.

Comment: they provide at the moment only [fix](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XFhgY7h_eqbx3keDt8ZeZuwLusjP6JDX) for NET Standard version in 9.1.4, we also have success with IBM Support communication

Comment: IBM:
The issue was introduced in 9.1.4. The APAR is still open, so its not clear what future release it will be included in.